# Testing-library custom query Typescript error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-testing-library

In a current project using `react` with `jest` and `@testing-library/react`, I'm implementing custom queries to query the **text content** of components.

The custom query (built with testing-library's `buildQueries` method) I want to use receives two parameters (one is optional). When I want to add a second parameter, Typescript tells me that only one argument can be passed.

```
const queryAllByTextContent = (
  container: HTMLElement,
  text: string | RegExp,
  options?: QueryParameterOptions
): HTMLElement[] => {
  const { exact = false } = options ?? { };

  return queryAllByText(container, (content, node): boolean => {
    if (!node) {
      return false;
    }
    const nodeHasSearchText = nodeContainsSearchText({ searchText: text, exact, node });
    // eslint-disable-next-line unicorn/prefer-spread
    const childNodesDontHaveSearchText = Array.from(node.children).every(
      (childNode): boolean => !nodeContainsSearchText({ searchText: text, exact, node: childNode })
    );

    return nodeHasSearchText && childNodesDontHaveSearchText;
  });
};

const getMultipleError = (
  container: Element | null,
  text: string | RegExp
): string => `Found multiple elements with the text: ${text}`;
const getMissingError = (
  container: Element | null,
  text: string | RegExp
): string => `Unable to find an element with the text: ${text}`;

const [
  queryByTextContent,
  getAllByTextContent,
  getByTextContent,
  findAllByTextContent,
  findByTextContent
] = buildQueries(queryAllByTextContent, getMultipleError, getMissingError);
```

I have created a Github repository with a working example:

https://github.com/desudo/example-jest-with-react-testing-library

Most important files are:

`/test/helpers/textContentQueries.ts` -> `queryAllByTextContent`
`/test/component/Price.test.tsx`

**What I found out**:

The first parameter of the custom query **has to be** of type `string | RegExp`.
When I set the type to **just** a string, everything works as intended.

**IMPORTANT**

The example tests are just dummy tests to show the Typescript error.

---

Thank you for any hint or solution!

Comment: I'm not sure it is your custom query. Rather, I think it is your use of `queryAllBy`. You are passing the two arguments to `queryAllByText()` when, in the React testing library it only takes one argument (plus options object). This statement: "_instead of getByText(node, 'text') you do getByText('text')_" can be found [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/cheatsheet/#queries).

Comment: Doesn't that refer to when `getByText` is used in a test case? `queryAllByText` is used before the query is being built and exported with the `buildQueries` method. The TypeScript Intellisense also suggests that `queryAllByText` can receive `(container: HTMLElement, id: Matcher, options: SelectorMatcherOptions)`

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for the information. I will add code snippets accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of fixing this issue is to add the parameter `options?: QueryParameterOptions` to both `getMultipleError` and `getMissingError`.

This is due to the type that is being defined under the hood of `buildQueries`.

I certainly do not like this solution because we are not using the options parameter in either of these two methods.